# Complete group multiplication table with 6 elements.

Tags: group-theory

The following group multiplication table shall be completed. How many possibilities are there? (This is an exercise from a textbook).

$\begin{array}{c|cccccc}
\cdot & a & b & c & d & e & f \\ 
\hline
a &  &  &  &  & & \\
b &  &a &e &  & & \\ 
c &  &  &  &  & & \\ 
d &  &  &  &  & & \\
e &  &d &  &  & & \\
f &  &  &  &  & & 
\end{array}$

So we have $bb=a, bc=e$ and $eb=d$. What I can derive here is that $$(bc)b=eb=d=b(cb),$$ $$(bb)c=ac=b(bc)=be$$ and $$b(bb)=ba=(bb)b=ab.$$ Of corse when you know that there are only two groups of order 6 ($S_3$ and $\mathbb{Z}6$) you can just check which one is compatible with this table, however I think this is not the idea of this exercise.

Comment: The two groups are $S_3$ and $\mathbb Z_6$

Comment: yes${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: In my view the line with header $a$ is missing because of some slip of the typesetter. In any case, I don't see how you conclude from the given data that $a$ must be the neutral element.

Comment: I found another argument, since $da = d$ and $ea=e$, $a$ must be the neutral element, agree?

Comment: What you have in the table doesn't to match your argument, either in the main text or in the comment. In the table, I only see three entries, corresponding to $bb=a$, $bc=e$, $eb=d$, which is completely different from what you seem to be using. (For example, you write $eb=a$...) Is there something wrong with your typesetting?

Comment: Thank your for pointing this out. I have corrected the errors, it was not the typesetting it was my brain male-functioning!